# Postgres: delete duplicate rows with bi-directional relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with a Postgres database which has a bi-directional join table. The data is being cleaned up and we no longer want the duplicates.

The table has 3.4m rows, but a snapshot is like this:

```
sentence_id  |  translation_id
-------------|----------------
77           |  1276
1276         |  77
77           |  2481
2481         |  77
77           |  380381
380381       |  77
```

This query identifies the pairs:

```
select s.sentence_id, x.sentence_id
from tmp s, tmp x
where s.sentence_id = x.translation_id
and x.sentence_id = s.translation_id
```

What I am trying to do is to delete one of the duplicate pairs, eg, with rows 1 and 2 (77, 1276 and 1276,77), I want to retain only one row. It doesn't matter which one.

Example output would be:

```
sentence_id  |  translation_id
-------------|----------------
77           |  1276
77           |  2481
77           |  380381
```

How can I handle this in SQL only on Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:  delete a row if `sentence_id` is greater than `translation_id` *and* the inverse relationship exists:

```
delete from tmp
    where tmp.translation_id > tmp.sentence_id and
          exists (select 1
                  from tmp tmp2
                  where tmp2.sentence_id = tmp.translation_id and
                        tmp.sentence_id = tmp2.translation_id
                 );
```

Having said that, deleting lots of rows from a relatively large table can be inefficient.  It might be better to just stash the values in a temporary table, truncate the first table, and re-insert the values:

```
create table tmp_tmp as
    select sentence_id, translation_id
    from tmp
    where tmp.translation_id > tmp.sentence_id and
          exists (select 1
                  from tmp tmp2
                  where tmp2.sentence_id = tmp.translation_id and
                        tmp.sentence_id = tmp2.translation_id
                 );

truncate table tmp;

insert into tmp(sentence_id, translation_id)
    select sentence_id, translation_id
    from tmp_tmp;
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, actually the delete worked fine: ran in 24.2s on a db running on my laptop, albeit it with 8GM of VM memory and indexes on each column.

Comment: @ardochhigh . . . I'm glad the simpler delete version worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the internal column `ctid` for this:

```
delete from tmp 
where ctid not in (select min(ctid)
                   from tmp
                   group by least(sentence_id, translation_id), 
                            greatest(sentence_id, translation_id));
```

Comment: @Used_By_Already: sure, why not? `not in` isn't as bad as its reputation. And 3.4 million isn't really that big. But I agree, Gordon's statement is most probably a lot faster.

Comment: very interesting about ctid